# Struggling with batch script for editing local user accounts, multiple variables at play

Tags: batch-file

I want to change the local admin password to something more secure across the environment. The problem that is that the current state of the environment varies. For the most part, the standard administrator account is enabled across the board with a weak password that I would like to update. The problem is that in some cases and left the default admin account disabled and created a new account called "admin".

Then, to make matters more complicated, there is another local account that should be a standard user called "user" but I know in some places it has been made an admin as well when it should not be, and in other places it has not been created at all.

I have since standardized and automated the creation of these accounts during our build / deployment process, so all new computers are going out with the correct setup:

- default local administrator account ".\administrator" enabled, with secure password
- standard local account "user" with normal strength password

But in order to bring the rest of our environment in line with this, i'm trying to write a script that will do the following:

1. check to see if the default local administrator account is enabled
2. if it is, set the password to the new more secure one (a handful of devices will already have it set correctly but that's fine). if it doesn't, enable it
3. check to see if an account called "admin" exists
4. if it does, delete it. if it doesn't, great
5. check to see if "user" account exists
6. if it does exist, create it as a standard user. if it doesn't exist, ensure that it is not a local admin

i am comfortable doing most of these things with net user commands, but it is stringing them together into a script with the conditional logic that i am struggling with. Been looking at for /F loops but not sure this is the best way to go about it?

Would really appreciate a point in the right direction. Even if it is just some advice on which commands to read up on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do not support off topic questions, but the new year is still fresh. I am not sure why you want to use batch for this as there are much better ways, like policies to do this, but anyway, here goes:

```
@echo off
for /f %i in ('net user') do (
     if /i "%%i"=="user" echo net user %%i /delete
     echo net user user /add SomePassword
     if /i "%%i"=="admin" echo net user %%i /delete
     if /i "%%i"=="administrator" echo net user %%i NewPassword99
)
```

This might not be everything you need, but the question is off topic and I am just leading you in the direction.

The for loop simply assigns each whitespace (space/tab/newline) delimited word to token `%%i`. Instead of checking user `user`'s permission, just delete and recreate it regardless. then check for admin, delete it and check Administrator password. You can add, ammend what you want from there.

Once happy with the results, remove each `echo` statement in the strings within the loop to perform the actual `net user` command, this is to display on screen what would happen if you are to run it, it is just a safeguard.